# Android market app version distribution

Tags: android, google-play, usage-statistics

Is there any way on the Android Market that I can see the distribution of versions of my app among users?

For example, if I have an app with v1.0 and 2.0, can I see the percentage of the users still using 1.0? This would be extremely helpful in determining what versions should I continue to support in the server.

Comment: As soon as you release v 2.0, won't people with 1.0 be notified and automatically be updated to v 2.0 or whatever the latest is?

Comment: But if you have multiple apks active at the same time, i don't think the android market keeps track of which apk "version" was downloaded. You can check your google checkout account to see if that has any information there as to which version was downloaded - but that's only for paid applications. Sorry. that's as far what i know about the market. HTH.

Comment: may be in future version releases, you can add the "code" info to the client requests so that your server knows which version is being served. Just a thought for future updates...

Comment: That's a nice idea. Just wondering if I can do it without extra code. I thought it's a common enough case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android market doesn't provide this distinction, but you could add this code to your app so that server know which version is trying to access it.